# ImportError: No module named flask.ext.cors

Tags: python, flask

I have an error

```
2017-01-15 00:49:14,075 :Error running WSGI application
2017-01-15 00:49:14,076 :ImportError: No module named flask.ext.cors
```

It happened after I added this:

```
from flask.ext.cors import CORS

cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

Comment: So you installed that Flask extension?

Comment: pip install -U flask-cors

Answer (score 7):

Did you just forget to install this package?

Install the extension using pip.

```
pip install -U flask-cors
```

And you can add this

`from flask.ext.cors import CORS` or `from flask_cors import CORS`.

Check out [Flask CORS document](http://flask-cors.corydolphin.com/en/latest/api.html#extension)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try `from flask_cors import CORS`

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo pip install -U flask
sudo pip install -U flask-cors
sudo pip install -U future
```